# javascript file used in django is getting loaded with html content

Tags: javascript, html, django

html code:

```
(my_django) [ my_lpar]# cat addlpar/templates/check.html
<html><head><title>hello</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<p> hey wassup </p>
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/check.js' %}"> </script>
/div>
</body>
</html>
```

js code:

```
alert()
```

When I start server, alert is not executed. So when I inspected the source of javascript file, from browser , check.js file is same as check.html:

from browser:

```
<html><head><title>hello</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<p> hey wassup </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/check.js"> </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And no obvious error is thrown in runserver:

```
(my_django) [my_lpar]# python3.5 manage.py runserver <ip:port>

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 28, 2020 - 17:35:07
Django version 2.1, using settings 'my_lpar.settings'
Starting development server at <ip:port>
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[28/Apr/2020 17:35:10] "GET /static/js/check.js HTTP/1.1" 200 168
[28/Apr/2020 17:35:11] "GET /static/js/check.js HTTP/1.1" 200 168
[28/Apr/2020 17:35:11] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 168
```

Please somebody help me to solve this weird issue. Why Am I not able to see javascript content.??

Comment: Can you share your urls? Both requests in your logs are going to `/static/js/check.js`, what's the path to the view that is serving your html?

Comment: @lain Shelvington

urls.py file of app:

urlpatterns = [
        url ('', views.index, name="index"),
]

projects urls.py:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
        url('', include('addlpar.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

views.py:

def index(request):
        return render (request, 'check.html');

Comment: @

urls.py file of app:

 urlpatterns = [
   url ('', views.index, name="index"),
 ]

projects urls.py:

 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path
 from django.conf.urls import url, include

 urlpatterns = [
   url('', include('addlpar.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 ]

views.py:

 def index(request):
   return render (request, 'check.html');

Comment: how to debug this. Any idea?